# Is the quote "Don't let others lead you, decide your own path" really from the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, identification-request, shloka

According to several sites, the following quote is from the Vedas. Some state that it is from the Atharva Veda but the verse no. is not mentioned.

> "Do not be led by others, awaken your own mind, amass your own
>   experience, and decide for yourself your own path." — Vedas (specifically Atharva Veda, according to some sites)

Can anyone confirm the Veda/book/chapter this verse is taken from?

Comment: if it was truly from the Atharva veda, why do they not give the verse #? why not ask the websites that quote it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this quote is [specifically meant for women](http://agniveer.com/women-in-vedas/). The wording may be different, but from Veda.

[Rig Veda 10.159](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10159.htm) is dedicated to Saci Paulomi.

A women speaks after waking up in morning:

“My destiny is as glorious as the rising sun. I am the flag of my home and society. I am also their head. I can give impressive discourses. My sons conquer enemies. My daughter illuminates the whole world. I myself am winner of enemies. My husband has infinite glory. I have made those sacrifices which make a king successful. I have also been successful. I have destroyed my enemies.”

> 1.YON Sun hath mounted up, and this my happy fate hate mounted high. I knowing this, as conqueror have won my husband for mine own.
>
> 2 I am the banner and the head, a mighty arbitress am I: I am
>   victorious, and my Lord shall be submissive to my will.
>
> 3 **My Sons are slayers of the foe**, my Daughter is a ruling Queen: I am
>   victorious: o’er my Lord my song of triumph is supreme.
>
> 4 Oblation, that which Indra gave and thus grew glorious and most
>   high,— This have I offered, O ye Gods, and rid me of each rival wife.
>
> 5 Destroyer of the rival wife, Sole Spouse, victorious, conqueror, The
>   others' glory have I seized as ’twere the wealth of weaker Dames.
>
> 6 I have subdued as conqueror these rivals, these my fellow-wives,
>   That I may hold imperial sway over this Hero and the folk.

---